# Android - can mainThread handlers cause memory leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, handler

I am curious why the below is a memory leak because the mHandler is created on the mainThread and now when onDestroy is called wont it just kill the thread ? how can the handler exists after the activity is destroyed ? i have not made a new thread. Am i to understand that a handler if it has things i the message queue will remain even after a thread is destroyed ?

The reference doc im reading is [here](https://techblog.badoo.com/blog/2014/08/28/android-handler-memory-leaks/)
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Handler's are mainly used to post events to the Thread's MessageQueue.**Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue.**

so when you post a runnable with a delay, and exit from the activity, the MainThread will not be destroyed, as there are still events in the MessageQueue to be processed after a delay, so this can cause a **memoryLeak** as your anonymous innerclass of runnable is holding the reference of **activity** **instance** .

so make sure to remove all the messages in **onStop()** of Activity by calling

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

this will clear all the pending message and callbacks before leaving your activity.

Comment: so your saying if a handler has messages in the queue it must continue running even if activity that it was created on finishes, right ?

Comment: And in the case of my example, the handler is associated with the mainThread. and i am posting runnables to the main threads looper. now when the activity calls onDestroy since there are messages still in the mainThreads looper queue the GC will not collect the activity ? or is it that the GC will not collect the activity because of the reference the runnable holds ? See what i mean ?lets say the runnable did not have an activity reference ? would it be leaked still?

Comment: @j2emanue if your runnable is not holding any activity reference, in that case activity leak will not happen, but still main thread will be alive as it has to finish the events in the Message queue posted by the runnable.

Comment: @j2emanue that is why it is always recommended to avoid anonymous inner class runnable if you are sure your innerclass will outlive the Activity lifecycle, or better to clear the message queue posted by handler when your activity is leaving the Screen.

Comment: This is really an eye opener. All this time I thought main thread would end  as soon as onDestroy() is called.

Comment: So, Even you're using this way: private static Handler test = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); and test.postdelay(runnable,delayTime); and post a runnable with delayTime in Activity. and It may will lead a leak of memory. Right? In other words, runnable hold the instance of activity. so even you closed the activity but the msg(work as a runnable) is still pending in the MessageQueue.

Comment: Is it possible to deal with UI tasks without removing messages manually(including to remove it on onDestory of BaseActivity) and make sure there is no memory leaking?

Answer (score 0):

They can, but not of the Handler- of the Runnable that's posted.  The way a Handler works is that it's associated with a Thread.  That Thread must have a Looper.  A Looper has a message queue.  When you postDelayed, you add the Runnable to that Looper's message queue.  So the Thread itself has a reference to the Runnable.  So that Runnable would be leaked, and if non-static the parent class will be leaked.